# Compare column from two files and print the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files:

```
file1:

A1
A3
A5
A7
A9

file2:

A1  B1  C1  D1
A2  B2  C2  D2
A3  B3  C3  D3
A4  B4  C4  D4
A5  B5  C5  D5

output:
A1  B1  C1  D1
A3  B3  C3  D3
A5  B5  C5  D5
```

I have a huge amount lines, and I tried grep -f, it did not work.

Who can use python to work on this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -f` should work.

```
$ cat file1.txt
A1
A3
A5
A7
A9

$ cat file2.txt
A1  B1  C1  D1
A2  B2  C2  D2
A3  B3  C3  D3
A4  B4  C4  D4
A5  B5  C5  D5

$ grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
A1  B1  C1  D1
A3  B3  C3  D3
A5  B5  C5  D5
```

Comment: Actually, it did not work. Since the file1.txt have around 100K rows. It's too big to run.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using python:

```
one = open('file1.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')

two  = open('file2.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')

out  = open('outfile.csv', 'w')

outputtext=  ''

for i in two:
    i = i.strip()
    for q in one:
        q = q.strip()
        if q in i and q != '' and i != '':

            outputtext += i
            outputtext += '\n'

out.write(outputtext)

out.close()
```